# Using Swift, is possible with UIAlertController prompt user to open location settings?

Tags: swift, xcode6, uialertcontroller

In my Swift app, I check if *locationServiceEnabled()*. If it returns false, I should prompt user, with UIAlertController, to location settings.
Is possible doing this?
I use this func to prompt to location settings of the app:

```
 func displayAlertToEnableLocationServicesApp()
{
    let alertController = UIAlertController(
        title: "Location Access is Turned Off",
        message: "In order to locate your position, please open settings and set location access to 'While Using the App'",
        preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .Default) { (action) in
        if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
        }
    }
    alertController.addAction(openAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

But this func open settings app, and not location setting.
I need to open (settings -> privacy -> location)

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. In iOS 8 apps can directly launch the device settings, are you asking if you can do that from within a UIAlertController? The reason I'm not sure what you're asking is because of course you can launch a UIAlertController to prompt the user to do something, so there must be another part to your question which isn't obvious.

Comment: Yes, with UIAlertController and open (settings -> privacy -> location)

Answer (score 8):

from iOS8 you can open Settings system location from custom app.

**Swift 3**

```
let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Geolocation is not enabled", message: "For using geolocation you need to enable it in Settings", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default) { value in 
    let path = UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString
    if let settingsURL = URL(string: path), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsURL)
    }
})
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

viewController.present(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 2.3**

```
let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Geolocation is not enabled", message: "For using geolocation you need to enable it in Settings", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .Default) { value in
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
})
alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

viewController.presentViewController(alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This open settings location of app, but not general settings location

Comment: I actually would prefer this approach because it takes the user directly to the app's settings (which includes location for that app) as opposed to the list of all apps on their phone that they would have to sort through to enable it on one app.

Comment: @NicLaughter, `prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES` also good solution. Of course it depends from conceptual side.

Comment: Right, I was just pointing out that this may be a preferred approach because it takes you directly to the settings for the app itself, as opposed to the entire list of apps that have location services.

Answer (score 7):

First configure the URL Schemes in your project. You will find it in Target -> Info -> URL Scheme. click on + button and type prefs in URL Schemes

[image]

Now replace `if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)`
with  `if let url = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"))`

and following are all the available url's

- prefs:root=General&path=About
- prefs:root=General&path=ACCESSIBILITY
- prefs:root=AIRPLANE_MODE
- prefs:root=General&path=AUTOLOCK
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE/CELLULAR_USAGE
- prefs:root=Brightness
- prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth
- prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME
- prefs:root=FACETIME
- prefs:root=General
- prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard
- prefs:root=CASTLE
- prefs:root=CASTLE&path=STORAGE_AND_BACKUP
- prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL
- prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES
- prefs:root=ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
- prefs:root=MUSIC
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=EQ
- prefs:root=MUSIC&path=VolumeLimit
- prefs:root=General&path=Network
- prefs:root=NIKE_PLUS_IPOD
- prefs:root=NOTES
- prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID
- prefs:root=Phone
- prefs:root=Photos
- prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList
- prefs:root=General&path=Reset
- prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone
- prefs:root=Safari
- prefs:root=General&path=Assistant
- prefs:root=Sounds
- prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK
- prefs:root=STORE
- prefs:root=TWITTER
- prefs:root=FACEBOOK
- prefs:root=General&path=USAGE prefs:root=VIDEO
- prefs:root=General&path=Network/VPN
- prefs:root=Wallpaper
- prefs:root=WIFI
- prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING

Comment: the url isnt opening

Answer (score 0):

Open Application Settings. Xcode 8.2.1 - iOS 10

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```